# imprimir un area y borrar link y numero de pagina

Tags: javascript, print, imprimir

Tengo esta funcion para el boton de imprimir:

```
<script src="js/jquery.PrintArea.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#printButton").click(function(){
        var mode = 'iframe'; //popup
        var close = mode == "popup";
        var options = { mode : mode, popClose : close};
        $("div.printableArea").printArea( options );
    });
});
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="printButton">Imprimir</a>  
            <div class="printableArea">
            aqui lo que voy a imprimir

            </div>
```

pero me imprime el link de la pagina como hago para eliminar el link de arriba de la pagina y al pie de pagina eliminar el numero de paginas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### En general

El encabezado y el pie de página a la hora de imprimir no se pueden configurar desde la página web, es parte de la configuración del navegador. Es el usuario el que debe elegir no añadir esos datos:

**Con encabezado**
[image: Con encabezado]

**Sin encabezado**
[image: Sin encabezado]

Pero en algunos navegadores funciona lo siguiente:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page 
    {
        size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
        margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    }

    html
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
        margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
    }

    body
    {
        border: solid 1px blue ;
        margin: 10mm 15mm 10mm 15mm; /* margin you want for the content */
    }
    </style>
```

estos CSS aplican solo a la impresora y ocultan los márgenes